# Calculating NDVI in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, satellite-image

I'm trying to create a small shiny app that could plot the NDVI from a tiff file loaded from a folder.

Here is what I've done :

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dbplyr)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)



ui<-fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("NDVI calculation"),
  
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('layer', 'Choose Layer', multiple=FALSE, accept='tiff')
  ),
  imageOutput(outputId = "ndvi")
  
  
)

server<-function(input, output) {
  
    output$ndvi <- renderPlot({
     
      S2 <- input$layer
      
      S2 <- stack(S2)
      
      S2 <- brick(S2)
      
      S2_ndvi <- (S2[[4]] - S2[[1]]) / (S2[[4]] + S2[[1]])
      

      
      plot(S2_ndvi,
           main = "NDVI of site 12RD8",
           axes = FALSE, box = FALSE)    })
    
    
  }
  
  
  


shinyApp( ui=ui, server=server)
```

But I get this error message:

> **Warning: Error in stack.default: at least one vector element is required**

Could someone help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, the shiny app is trying to create a stack from nothing in the server as when the app is loaded, input$layer is null. The easiest way to hide that error until a layer is uploaded is to use `req()`. You place the required inputs inside `req()` and the app won't run that chunk of code unless those inputs have a value.

```
server<-function(input, output) {
  
    output$ndvi <- renderPlot({
     req(input$layer)

      S2 <- input$layer
      S2 <- stack(S2)
      S2 <- brick(S2)
      S2_ndvi <- (S2[[4]] - S2[[1]]) / (S2[[4]] + S2[[1]])
      
      plot(S2_ndvi,
           main = "NDVI of site 12RD8",
           axes = FALSE, box = FALSE)    })
      
  }
```

**Edit**
You could also write an if else statement based on if input$layer is null `is.null(input$layer)` and when it is null ask the user to upload a file

Comment: Thanks you very much eco-Alys ! 
But now when the layer is loading the app crashes and I get this error message in the R console: `Warning in stack.data.frame(x, ...) :
  non-vector columns will be ignored
Erreur : C stack usage  15922880 is too close to the limit`

Do you have an idea of what could generate such error ?